# Im unable to rip a couple of DVD´s in linux ?? Acidrip/Handbrake/DVDRip did not work

Tags: vlc, dvd

Yesterday i went to a Thrift store 
(recyclestore, 2nd hands goods) i bought
5 dvds for 1.50 euro total there (around 1 
dollar i guess,. for all 5 combined).
I tried ripping these DVDś at home with
use of AcidRip , Handbrake and DVDRip in linux
Xubuntu 18.04 LTS, On several different
computers in my home, 2 desktops and a laptop.
the DVDs are

Taxi 1 , 2 ,3
Daylight Robbery and
The day the Earth stood still.

I could only rip Daylight Robbery in the normal way as should with Either Handbrake or Acidrip. I did not try DVDRip on this title.
Now, all other DVDs cannot be ripped,
the result is a distorted video playback
or none at all. I tried all combinations 
with the above 3 rippers, nothing worked.
during ripping either the ripping program
crashes or goes extremely slow 700 minutes for 700 mb, and resulting in a corrupt video file.
I cannot play the remaining 4 DVDś with
VLC Linux (xubuntu), What happens is that
VLC Crashes, or stops playback.
Their regioncodes are 2, its my region, and
as all dvds i have. this should not be
the cause of the problem. right ?
Now i looked on the back of these movieboxes,
and there it says with 3 from 4
DVD-9. The remaining one says DVD-5, and
the working one, Daylight Robbery also DVD-5.
Can it be that my dvd drives cannot read 
DVD-9 format ? or rip it ?
Is this Encrypted ? Are these DVDs protected ?
Now comes the weird part;
i tried the 4 not rippable, corrupted video
output at playback DVDs in my Xbox One,
and they simply worked. so i could view them.

What is going on here ?

i have different DVD+r/DVD+rw drives in my
computers, but i never had this problem.
a couple of years ago i had converted all
of my 60 or 70 dvd collection to mp4.
with those same pcs. 
this never made me have any problem with a
disc, dvd or any protection ....

I was not going to do anything illegal with
the copies though i was going to make,only for 
backup and for use with my mediaplayer, for
comfort viewing.

can anyone tell me what is going on here

Answer (score 3):

i Went around and googled for some time i found 
the solution on how to rip copy protected dvds
in linux xubuntu or acidrip/handbrake

Make sure these 2 packages are installed
(from within Synaptic Package Manager)

```
libdvdread4     (i already had this one)

libdvd-pkg      (i missed this one)
```

then exit Synaptic and type in a terminal the following to start downloading the dvd decrypting lib

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

you get a screen which prompts for downloading/build
with a yes and a no, choose yes, and wait.
the lib starts building, it may take a little
while.

after this, (may need reboot) and you can play and
in (most) cases rip or copy protected dvds.
take caution with legality, the playback of encrypted dvds is not the same as ripping them, and there is
a difference between making a personal backup, and one
for spread around the net!. Please do not spread
your dvd copies in the wild. I am not responsible

I believe on Windows computers this is directly 
possible without extra libs or drivers.
(am not certain, but windows pcs can play such dvds
 without extra drivers or libs i believe)

another way to get a non working handbrake working is
by NOT installing the snap version of the program but
search for it in package manager and use that version.
this is because the snap version does not have sufficient
rights to read the following folder;

```
/media/<user>/<dvd disc>
```

use this folder if you cannot rip a dvd with handbrake,
instead when /dev/dvd or /dev/sr0 are not working to rip a disc.
I use this folder now for all ripping with handbrake
and i havent gotten any error till now, it (handbrake) 
also is twice as fast compared to dvd::rip or ogmrip.

Comment: Great advice!  I had a problem with handbrake failing to decrypt a DVD I own, and producing "blocky" or "pixelated" video.  Your advice to uninstall the snap package and install using apt fixed the problem.